How to call BLE StartDiscovery with sdbus-c++ on DBus consistently?
I started with this blog post Me and the Devil BlueZ: Reading BLE Sensors From C++. Since the repo had been archived I forked it, added a CI build and fixed a few minor issues here https://github.com/parsley72/NoiseCollectorBLE.
This works fine on Ubuntu but when I try the same code on my embedded device I just get:
interfaceAddedCallback(path = /org/bluez/hci0) *** UNEXPECTED SIGNAL ***
interfaceAddedCallback(path = /org/bluez/hci0) *** UNEXPECTED SIGNAL ***

Running bluetoothctl then scan le works fine so there's no issue with signal quality or hardware.
How can I do this in using sdbus-c++ so it works consistently on different devices?

How did you create the bluezProxy? Are you calling the method on the correct object? What differences do you see in dbus-monitor --system or in busctl monitor --system between your call and the working one?
